# Generating m samples of length n

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics

I have been trying to create 500 samples of length 50 (each sample  is exp(50, 3)) but I have failed so many times. I do not know how to create a vector of length 500 of samples. I´m a rookie in R. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The following command creates a $50 \times 500$ matrix. The columns correspond to the samples.

```
replicate(500, rexp(50, 3))
```

The random values are distributed exponentially with rate $\lambda = 3$.

The command `exp(50, 3)` creates a vector with 50 random values. The function `replicate` is used to repeat the command 500 times.